# Guice provision exception

Tags: java, servlets, guice, servlet-filters, nexus

I am writing a custom filter for nexus to do authentication . when I add the filter by writing a filter module similar to [sourcecode](https://github.com/sonatype/nexus-oss/blob/master/plugins/restlet1x/nexus-restlet1x-plugin/src/main/java/org/sonatype/nexus/security/filter/NexusSecurityFilterModule.java) .I am getting a guice provision exception. I don't know what is the real cause . it just says null pointer exception.

```
Sisu - Problem adding: org.sonatype.guice.bean.locators.LazyBeanEntry@7bb3bc to: org.apache.shiro.web.filter.mgt.DefaultFilterChainManager@5b460d via: org.sonatype.security.web.guice.SecurityWebModule$FilterChainManagerProvider@1d31aaa
com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Guice provision errors:

1) Error in custom provider, java.lang.NullPointerException
  at org.sonatype.guice.bean.binders.LocatorWiring
  while locating org.sonatype.nexus.security.filter.authc.PasswordDecryptor
    for field at org.sonatype.nexus.security.filter.authc.NexusSecureHttpAuthenticationFilter.passwordDecryptor(NexusSecureHttpAuthenticationFilter.java:20)
  while locating net.collab.iaf.sso.authentication.rest.CTFAuthenticationFilter
  at file:/media/blackhole/temp/nexus/nexus-bundle-template-2.6.1-SNAPSHOT-bundle/nexus-bundle-template-2.6.1-SNAPSHOT/../sonatype-work/nexus/plugin-repository/authentication-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/authentication-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/
  at file:/media/blackhole/temp/nexus/nexus-bundle-template-2.6.1-SNAPSHOT-bundle/nexus-bundle-template-2.6.1-SNAPSHOT/../sonatype-work/nexus/plugin-repository/authentication-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/authentication-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/
  while locating javax.servlet.Filter annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=authcBasic)

1 error
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1006) [sisu-guice-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
```

My custom filter module is same as the source code file I gave above in link, with just filters for authcBasic and authcNxBasic . here I have a custom filter by name CTFAuthenticationFilter instead of the NexusSecureHttpAuthenticationFilter . Please give some directions to solve this issue .
snip of my filter module is as follows

```
@Override
    protected void configure() {
        requireBinding(FilterChainResolver.class);
        logger.info("I am inside collabnetsso");
        bindAuthcFilter("authcBasic", false, "Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager API");
        bindAuthcFilter("authcNxBasic", true, "Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager API (specialized auth)");

    }

    private void bindAuthcFilter(String name, boolean fakeAuthSchem, String applicationName) {
        logger.info("I am inside collabnetsso authc module");
        CTFAuthenticationFilter filter = new CTFAuthenticationFilter();
        filter.setApplicationName(applicationName);
        filter.setFakeAuthScheme(Boolean.toString(fakeAuthSchem));
        bindNamedFilter(name, filter);
    }
```

This appears strange as it happens only sometimes . If it happens two times consecutively , In these 2 times my authentication doesn't happen . But again if I restart , exceptions vanish and it starts working like a charm and authentication happen as desired .
This brings in doubt like is there any race condition happening in nexus ?
Or is it that Google guice expects something and which is not available sometimes.